# Python RSA encoder doesn't work when message is too large

Tags: python, rsa

I'm trying to make an RSA encoder/decoder that takes message "m", converts it to a string of ascii, and then encodes it. When I try to decode that number, it gives me something completely wrong. I've tried putting in small numbers as the message and not converting it to ascii and that works fine. I figure it must have something to do with the size of the number. How would I fix this?

```
def encode():
    P = int(input("Enter P value (must be prime): "))   #29
    Q = int(input("Enter Q value (must be prime): "))   #41
    n = P * Q                                           #1189
    phiN = (P - 1)*(Q - 1)                              #1120
    e = int(input("Enter e value (1 < e < phiN): "))    #9
    d = pow(e, -1, phiN)                                #249
    print("Your public key is: (n = " + str(n) + ", e = " + str(e) + ")")
    print("Your private key is: (n = " + str(n) + ", d = " + str(d) + ")")
    m = input("Message to encode: ")

    ascii_values = []
    strings = []

    # Converts every character in "m" (message) into ASCII value and append it to
    # ascii_values list
    for character in m:
        ascii_values.append(ord(character))

    # Converts every element in ascii_values list and converts it to a string
    # Appends to "strings" list
    for element in ascii_values:
        strings.append(str(element))

    #Makes all values 3-digits. Dunno if this is really needed
    i = 0
    while i < len(strings):
        while len(strings[i]) != 3:
            strings[i] = "0" + strings[i]
        i += 1

    # Takes "strings" list and joins elements together to make one long string
    a = "".join(strings)
    c = pow(int(a), e, n)
    print("Your encoded message is (" + str(c) + ") Use your private key to decode it")

def decode():
    d = int(input("Enter d value: "))
    n = int(input("Enter n value: "))
    c = int(input("Enter ciphertext (must be integer): "))
    m = pow(c, d, n)
    print("Your decoded message is (" + str(m) + ") Use a decoder to convert to text")
```

Comment: What numbers have you tried? At what point does the change happen?

Comment: Your `n` value is 1189.  `pow(c, d, n)` does an exponentiation in modulo n.  That means every message you provide will be reduced to the range (0,1188).  Any message larger than that is going to be lost.

Comment: I used P = 29, Q = 41, E = 9 as well as P = 2159947535959146091116171018558446546179, Q = 658558036833541874645521278345168572231473, E = 65537. I had the same problem with both, but I'm gonna try encoding to bytes like was suggested instead of my weird ASCII converter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you have to understand the encoding and encrypting difference.
RSA is an asymmetric encryption algorithm and not an encoding one like Base64.

The second thing is that it's not a good practice to convert a text to number like this before encrypting it. If you want there is another more simple way:

```
m_int = int( 'hello world'.encode().hex() , 16 ) # 126207244316550804821666916
```

which encodes string to bytes and then converts it to hex format and finally to a number.
To convert it back to string you should convert it to hex and then to bytes:

```
m_string = bytes.fromhex(hex(126207244316550804821666916)[2:]).decode() # 'hello world'
```

Now at your example you use RSA 11bit key, which means that the maximum length of your `m` cannot be more than 12 bits (126207244316550804821666916 is 88 bits) to be encrypted and decrypted properly.
So you should generate a bigger key by generating bigger primes.

I suggest you to check `pycryptodome` library if you want to make cryptography scripts.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. Do you have any links so I can learn exactly what these lines do? I think I understand the first one, but I'm not sure what the "[2:]" does in the second line.

Comment: hex(123456789) returns the hex value with prefix '0x' to help you realize that this string is hex value of something.
In python if you want to get rid of the first two characters of a string, you type at the end [2:].

hex(123456789) = '0x75bcd15'
hex(123456789)[2:] = '75bcd15'

You don't have to remove it just to convert it to number, but generally I don't recommend to keep the prefix when dealing with hex formats etc. because I had many errors in the past cause of it.